# Cómo puedo mostrar los "artículos no comprados" de una base de datos en MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tengo la tabla

Cliente:

```
idCliente, 
Nombre, 
Dirección,
Tel.
```

Compra:

```
idCompra, 
idCliente,
IdArticulo,
Unidades, 
fecha
```

Artículo:

```
idArticulo, 
Descripción, 
Precio,
Stock, 
StockMin, 
Nombre
```

Lo que necesito es hacer una consulta.... Que me muestre los artículos que NO han sido comprado.

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir hasta dónde has hecho y qué error tienes?

Comment: La base de datos ya está llenada, lo que necesito es hacer la consulta pero no sé hacerla :c

Answer (score 0):

¿Podrías dar mas especificación para poder ayudarte ? , así como lo entiendo con lo que has preguntado es que quieres mostrar cuantos artículos hay en stock, y para ello debes trabajar la **tabla Compra y la tabla Articulo** ,podrías partir analizando la lógica de tus tablas , ¿que pasa si el cliente hace una compra y esa compra no queda validada ,seria conveniente que descontara un articulo ? ¿Que pasa si quieres organizar los artículos de la compra para tu cliente en la cual fue validado ? explícanos un poco como es la lógica o que llevas y como es la **cardinalidad** de las tablas.

Una Compra puede estar relacionada a muchos artículos y un Articulo puede estar asociado a muchas Compras (* *) y en este punto hay que recordar **Normalizar**.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que tengo que realizar 3 consultas....

La primera es: "Obtener los Artículos que NO han sido comprados"... Entonces, no se cómo iría la consulta :/ apenas estoy aprendiendo

Answer (score 0):

```
select idArticulo from Articulos where idArticulo not in(select idArticulo from Compra)
```